# Nexus S Email Reception

Tags: email, cpanel, android

My dad recently purchased a Nexus S smartphone running Android 2.3.3. He owns a construction company and wants to be in touch with his email on the go, which is precisely why he purchased the smartphone.

I tried to set his email account, which comes from HostPapa, on his phone, but it doesn't receive any email. He gets his emails through Outlook and thanks to some obscure, long forgotten reason, HostPapa's mail server does not receive any email and forwards any received mail straight to the Outlook client.

How can I get that email to show up on his phone? If you need any extra details, I shall be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using POP3 to get your mail, Outlook is most likely removing the mail from the server after it downloads it. You will need to either tell Outlook to leave a copy on the server, or switch both over to IMAP, assuming the host supports it.

IMAP really is the way to go, as it will 'sync' changes between the devices. With POP, if he sends an email from the phone, for example, it will not show up as sent in Outlook, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But for the time being we'll stick with POP3. Turns out I was in error here: I didn't enter the right information the phone needed, even if it was fully able to connect to the server. So instead of using the CPanel username, I had to use the user@domain.com address/username. Now I feel like a dumbnut :)

I will still give you the accepted answer status for your answer, as it has given me insight on how to deal with this situation in the future.